# Approach for solving recurrence relations using induction

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

This recurrence relation is for the famous problem [The Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi).

We are given that: $T_n=2T_{n-1}+1$.

The problem here is, using induction, show that
$T_n=2^n – 1, n \ge 1$
To make things simpler, I'll give the vague solution that has been given to us by our teachers.

###### Solution that I can't seem to understand:

Observe that $T_1=1$. If $n\ge2,\,\,2T_{n-1}+1=2(2^{n-1}-1)+1=2^n-1=T_n$, verifying the formula.

Given the solution, I tried applying the induction method on it, but I just can't seem to solve this problem. Could somebody please look at the solution above and help me understand the approach to solve such problems?

---

Similarly there are other problems that have been mentioned in our books, but I think if I get the approach for one, I'll be able to solve the others. Listing one of them here just so that it may give you'll any hints.

###### Power set problem:

Given $S_n=2S_{n-1},n\ge1$ with $s_0=1$, using the recurrence relation for $S_n$, show that $Sn=2^n$, $n\ge0$.

Comment: Standard induction: (a) prove $T_1=f(1)$, (b) assuming $T_k=f(k)$ is true, prove $T_{k+1}=f(k+1)$, (c) claim $T_n=f(n)$ for all positive integer $n$ by induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking quite a few peers and checking some other online books, I finally found the correct answer to this induction proof. The proof goes as follows:

**Step 1. Induction Basis:**
Let us check if $P(1)$ base case holds true by plugging the value $n=1$.

$$T_n=2^n-1\\
T_1=2^1-1=2-1=1$$

As this proof is for [Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi), the number of steps involved in moving just a single disk is 1.
 Therefore, $P(1)$ holds true.

**Step 2. Induction Hypothesis:**
Let us assume that $P(k)$ holds true for arbitrary $k>=1$.

$$T_k=2^k-1\tag{1}\label{eq_one}$$

**Step 3. Induction Step:**
We need to prove that $P(k+1)$ also holds true. Hence we need to show that the following equality holds true.

$$T_{k+1}=2^{k+1}-1$$

As we already know, for moving $(n)^{th}$ disk in [TOH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) it takes $\mathbf{2(T_{n-1})+1}$ steps. 
Applying this same logic to our case of $(k+1)^{th}$ disk we get $T_{k+1}=2(T_k)+1$.

Solving $\mathbf{T_{k+1}=2(T_k)+1}$
$=2(2^k-1)+1 \stackrel{\eqref{eq_one}}*$
$=2.2^k-2+1$
$=2.2^k-1$
$=2^{k+1}-1$

---

Hence proved via Mathematical induction.

Answer (score 4):

When using mathematical induction to prove a certain property $P(n)$ we establish the basis of induction, e.g. that $P(1)$ is true and then prove that if $P(n-1)$ holds, the same happens to  $P(n)$. In this case, what must be shown is that if $T_{n-1} = 2^{n-1}-1$ then $T_{n} = 2^{n}-1$. In fact,
$$
T_{n} = 2 \underbrace{T_{n-1}}_{=2^{n-1}-1}+1 = 2 \cdot (2^{n-1}-1)+1 = 2^n-2+1 = 2^n-1. 
$$

Comment: $P(1)=2^1-1=1$, but how do I know this is true? I don't have a pattern on the L.H.S to compare with. Also, how did we establish that $T_{n-1}=2^{n-1}-1$?

Comment: Also, my problem is the 3rd step. I'm stuck at the 3rd step. 
$T_{k+1}=2^{k+1}-1$ and from here I'm lost. I don't know what needs to be proved from here on.

Comment: Also, in Mathematical induction, we we told to verify, $P(1)$, assume $P(k)$ is true and then verify $P(K+1)$ holds. Why have you taken $P(n-1)$ here?

Answer (score 2):

The solution given basically *is* induction, but with  steps and some text skipped.

As user @[Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) points out, the standard *weak* induction proofs (which is what you’ll be majorly/exclusively doing in intro to induction) go like this: For a statement $P(n)$ which is to be proven,

1. Prove that $P(1)$ holds, i.e. the statement is true when $n=1$ is plugged in. (**Base Case**)
2. *Assume* that $P(k)$ holds for some positive integer $k$, i.e. the statement is true when $n=k$ is plugged in. (**Induction Hypothesis**)
3. Based on (2), *prove* that $P(k+1)$ holds, i.e. the statement is true when $n=k+1$ is plugged in.

This works due to the theorem called the First Principle of Finite Induction, whose proof using the Well-Ordering Principle I link [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/induction/#proof-of-mathematical-induction). It basically states that:

> Let S be a set of positive integers with the following properties: 
> (i) The integer $1$ belongs to S,
> (ii) Whenever the integer $k$ is in S, the next integer $k+1$ must also be in S. 
> Then S is the set of all positive integers.

So a proof using induction would basically read like:

Let S be the set of all positive integers $n$ for which $P(n): T_n =2^n-1$ is true.

We know that $1\in S$, because $T_1=2^1-1$.

ASSUME that $k\in S$ for some positive integer $k$, i.e. $T_k=2^k-1$.

 Then, by the given recurrence, $T_{k+1}=2T_k+1$ we have $T_{k+1}=2^{k+1}-1$.

 This means that $k+1\in S$.

 By the First Principle of Finite Induction, $S$ is the set of all positive integers. But since S is the set of all integers for which $P(n)$ is true, it must mean that $P(n): T_n=2^n-1$ must be true for all positive integers $n$. Hence proved.

We generally omit all references to the set S in proofs by induction, and just go : P(1), check. Assume P(k) is true. P(k+1), check. Hence proved.

 I hope you can now write a proof using the three-step algorithm presented above.

Comment: Can you answer my doubts, posted in the comments of the answer posted by @PierreCarre?

Comment: First comment: we ASSUMED that $T_{n-1}=2^{n-1}$. Second comment: after proving that, you don’t need to prove anything. Just write “and hence the proof is complete, by mathematical induction”. Third comment: both are equivalent. We just prove that if a positive integer belongs to the solution set, then the next positive integer belongs to the solution set  too.

Comment: Okay, one final doubt, $T_{1}=2^1−1=1$ how do I tell if this is true or not? Usually, in case of other problems there is a pattern on the L.H.S which helps us to determine whether the answer achieved belongs to the sequence or not (ex. $1+2+3+....n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$).

Comment: $T_1=1$ is found by hit and trial.

Comment: No, Let me put it this way. I have 1 as the value. But how can I tell this is the correct value? What if I had gotten 2 after solving this equation? How would I know that this value is true?

Comment: Okay. Look. The way induction helps us in finding patterns is that we see the initial few values ( which are often *extremely simple to the point that we can calculate them easily*) and guess a formula that could, intuitively, work. Then we try to prove the formula by induction. If you had found $T_1=2$ and had ascertained sufficiently that you didn’t make a silly error, then you wouldn’t guess the formula $T_n=2^n-1$. *I think the italicised part addresses your exact query*.